# How can I upload large files generated by a Glue job from an S3 bucket to an SFTP site?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Trying to upload a file generated by a glue job file from S3 bucket to SFTP site. Unable to establish the connection.

Trying to do this through the glue job or lambda function.

Tried the following approaches and its not working:

SFTP transfer family setup- which does work from lambda tmp directory to SFTP site. But its not able to handle huge files because of space allocation issue.

Paramiko module setup within glue job.

File to be SFTPed. Paramiko module not found is the error in glue job, while lambda function exits without error